# Cython boolean indexing optimization

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython, nan

What is the best way to convert the following code to `cython`

Given the following example:

```
#setup example data Z and A
Z = np.random.randn(10,10)
A = np.random.randn(10,10)
A[0,1] = np.nan
A[1,3] = np.nan
A[5,3] = np.nan
A[3,5] = np.nan

B = np.isnan(A).transpose()

C = Z[B * B.transpose()]
```

I want to optimize the type definition of `np.ndarray` B in the above example and optimize the creation of ndarray `C`.

I tried using setting B to uint8 and python and c++ bools.

`cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=2, cast=True]` however this yields little or no speedup

and

```
cdef np.ndarray[bool, ndim=2, cast=True]
```

where bool is either `from cpython cimport bool` or `from libcpp cimport bool` in both cases the above code will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to create a buffer which will take `np.nan` values is using `np.float_t` or `np.double_t`. If you try using a integer buffer the following error will raise:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float Nan to integer
```

Then, you could use something like:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] A, Z

Z = np.random.randn(10,10)
A = np.random.randn(10,10)
A[0,1] = np.nan
A[1,3] = np.nan
A[5,3] = np.nan
A[3,5] = np.nan
B = np.isnan(A).transpose()
C = Z[B * B.transpose()]
```